# An ideal is radical if and only if $x^2\in I\Rightarrow x\in I$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I was trying to prove the following:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Suppose $I$ is an ideal of $R$. Then $I$ is a radical ideal if and only if for $x\in R$ such that $x^2\in I$ then $x\in I$.

One direction is very easy. If you suppose $I$ is radical then the result is immediate.

The other direction is not so easy. We have to prove that for any $n$, $x^n\in I\Rightarrow x\in I$. I tried to prove it by induction, but there is some trouble when $n$ is odd. I think the problem can be reduced to prove it when $n$ is an odd prime.

But I don't know if this is the best approach. Perhaps it's better to suppose some $x$ is in all prime ideals containing $I$ and try to prove $x\in I$ but at first sight it seems more convoluted to do it that way. So, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume your condition $x^2\in I\implies x\in I$ holds.

Suppose $x^3\in I$. Then $x^4\in I$ since $I$ is an ideal, and $x^4=xx^3$.
Therefore $x^2\in I$ (as $(x^2)^2\in I$) and so $x\in I$.

See above for the $x^4\in I$ case.

Suppose $x^5\in I$. Then $x^6\in I$ since $I$ is an ideal, and $x^6=xx^5$.
Therefore $x^3\in I$ (as $(x^3)^2\in I$) and we have seen that implies
that $x\in I$.

And so on...

Comment: Nice answer. To give a unified presentation to this argument: it is easy to prove (e.g., by induction) that if $x^{2} \in I \implies x \in I$, then $x^{2^{n}} \in I \implies x \in I$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, if  $x^{k} \in I$, and $t_{k}$ is the smallest power of $2$ bigger than $k$, then $x^{t_{k}} = x^{t_{k}-k} \cdot x^{k} \in I$, whence $x \in I$.